# cv2.VideoWriter doesn't work well on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, opencv, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm using OpenCV v.4.1.0 on Jetson Nano to capture video with RPi camera and the module `cv2.VideoWriter` doesn't work well saving video. The file is empty.

I've proved `cv2.VideoWriter` on RPi 3B+ and it worked fine.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

capture_height = 720
capture_width = 1280
frame_rate = 21
display_width = 860
display_height = 640
flip_method = 0

gstr = ('nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),'
        'width=%s, height=%s,'
        'framerate= %s'
        'format=NV12 ! nvvidconv flip-method= %s ! video/x-raw,'   
        'width=%s, height=%s,'
        'format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! appsink'
        % (capture_width, capture_height, frame_rate, flip_method, 
        display_width, display_height))

filename = 'video.avi'
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gstr, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, float(frame_rate), 
                     (capture_width,capture_height),True)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    out.write(img)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code should show an image from RPi camera, and save a video with `.avi` format.

Comment: you could try a different codec?

Comment: I did it already, and still don't working :(

Comment: also it recognizes that codec: 
`>>> cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')`
`1145656920`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to this is typing:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, float(frame_rate),
                      (display_width, display_height), True)
```